# SSH remote script execution with arguments C

Tags: c, linux, ssh

I'm new to SSH. I have a simple `.c` code that add 2 numbers, I'm trying to find a way to execute that script remotely with SSH and pass those numbers in the same call, my code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    printf("hello world");

    int result;
    
    result=a+b;
    printf("%d",result);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the line I'm using to execute the script remotely
`ssh user@ip ./script`

Comment: The same way you would execute the program (not a script!) locally... by [parsing the arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) given to the executable?

Comment: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { ... }` and `ssh user@ip ./script 42 -1`

Comment: Where do `a` and `b` come from? That program won't execute locally or remotely.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code won't work because you don't have those variables a and b.

So there are two methods:

#1 With variables read from terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    printf("hello world");

    int result;
    int a, b;
    
    scanf("%d %d",&a, &b);


    result=a+b;
    printf("%d",result);
    
    return 0;
}
```

#2 With variables read from args

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    printf("hello world");

    int result;

    result= atoi(argv[1]) + atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("%d",result);

    return 0;
}
```

Also if you want to execute this on a remote server you must be sure where is this file on your remote server or if it's compiled there and you have an executable.
So the steps would be:

1.ssh user@ip

2.Be sure that your file is it where you except

3.gcc file.c -o out

4./out 2 3 (#2) or ./out and then give your numbers

If you want to automate this the best way is the put your commands from above in a script bash and then execute. If you have further problems please let me know.